# WordPress - Ajax call response with .well-known/captcha

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get data with ajax call on WordPress. But ajax response return .well-known/captcha as a result.

#### Response result:

```
<html><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;/.well-known/captcha/"></meta></head></html>
```

Comment: Would help if you updated the question to include the code that you're using.

Comment: I have this same issue right now (NOV 2022) on a number of sites and can verify it is from Siteground anti-bot check. Really breaks the page badly when jquery itself is being denied and is an HTML captcha response instead and then everything that uses jQuery then throws errors and stops execution as well. I wish they wouldn't block .JS files. They're not blocking the page itself but they are blocking a number of JS files, which I don't understand what that logic is to say an IP can load an https request to a PHP page but not the JS files on the same acount? There's no way to turn it off except

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you're probably getting this error on a site hosted with SiteGround. They implemented a new firewall which blocks requests based on IP etc. You can learn about it here: https://www.siteground.com/blog/new-anti-bot-ai/

The only resolution is to ask SiteGround to disable this feature for your site.

This is happening because your AJAX calling is being blocked by SiteGround to show a Captcha (which obviously you cannot fill in an AJAX call).

Comment: For others bumping into this issue: I contacted siteground via their livechat. They transfered me to ticket support. At first, the supoport agent said they couldn't turn off the captcha service as it would be a potential security risk. I explained them that I needed it turned off because I have an API running on my site that crashes too much because of it. That did the trick and they turned it off.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today and was told to clear my CloudFlare cache (which fixed it).

However, I will be leaving SiteGround unless this "feature" is turned off. I was mentioned in an important industry webinar and lost a lot of traffic and potential business as Siteground blocked everyone and the captcha did not work.